# Python IDE that you can highlight a method/class and jump to its definition

Tags: python, ide

I'm trying to use textmate, but I find it hard to navigate a project with it.

I admit I probably just don't know the the IDE well enough.

Is it possible to highlight a class or method and jump to its definition?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784/poll-which-python-ide-editor-is-the-best and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python

Comment: NetBeans supports that. Right-click, "Navigate", "Go to Declaration"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure that I understood you question, but if you look for an IDE for Python I would strongly recommand you have a look at [PyDev](http://pydev.org/)

It's by far the most feature-rich IDE for Python and it has a really active development team. And did I mention it's free and open source?

Answer (score 1):

[Wing IDE](http://www.wingide.com/) is an excellent IDE for python.

Answer (score 1):

I too have been looking for an IDE that makes this sort of thing *easy*.

About two hours ago I downloaded [Pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and it has blown me away.  This may be the coolest IDE I have ever used, for any language.  So far it seems to do everything that big IDEs like VisualStudio or Eclipse do (for many languages), only without the learning curve or resource consumption of those monsters.

It does exactly what you are asking... just right-click on any class, or a method, or pretty much anything else, Select "Go to Implementation" (or Declaration), and up it pops in a new tab.

So many other amazing slick features too... just try it!

There's a 30 day trial and after that it's pretty reasonable (like $29 for academic, $100 for individual, and $200 for a commercial team.  Oh and FREE if you have a bona fide OpenSource project that's been actively worked on for at least 3 months.)

(I apologize if this sounds like an advertisement.  I can assure you that it's not.  I'm just kind of... obsessive... about IDEs, and very frustrated that so few of them meet my standards.  I will revise this if I find any "caveats" but so far, so good.)

Comment: PyCharm is simply amazing. Too bad it costs $100, which makes it a no-no for small home-brew projects (for me anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), Python is only available for the commercial version.

If you're asking about a Python IDE, IDLE comes with Python already. I can also recommend [Boa Constructor](http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I just bought IDEA a few days ago, they have a dedicated python IDE coming up so I figured IDEA isnt' that great?

Answer (score 0):

WingIDE if you can fork out some cash will do what you want all bundled up and with little to no configuration effort.
Otherwise Eclipse with Aptana's pydev is free, and does exactly that, plus a lot more (ctrl+click pretty much anything for redirection and a lot of other useful things like pyc removal etc.).

Navigation problems though are usually symptomatic of more than just lack of tools. A decent structure to your projects and a version control system (even if you work locally and solo) would go a long way helping to address that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what functionality is available in textmate but would a simple search work? i.e. Ctrl+F with the query "def function" including the def part so you find the definition instead of a call?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of pyscripter http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/.  Has those features and more (and a regex checker!)

Open source of course.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio 3.0

The PyDev team is now operating under the auspices of Aptana, which makes Aptana Studio 3 - an Eclipse customisation - preferable to the 2-step process of first downloading Eclipse, and then installing the PyDev extension.

Aptana comes pre-configured for Python (and others), and in addition features custom support for Django projects [including JavaScript support].

The product is fast and responsive, and features powerful meta-level functionality such as jumping to the definition of a callable, deducing object fields from **init** initialisation, module browsing, very good code completion, and more...

Thus far, out of Eclipse+PyDev, NetBeans Python Edition and Aptana Studio 3, based on relatively extensive personal testing, AS3 wins hands down.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small Bundle/Command for TextMate that can accomplish Python Jump to definition for 99% of cases:

```
FUNC="$TM_CURRENT_WORD"
DIR="$TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY"
OUTPUT=''

# Define the class or function definition string that we're looking for.
FUNCDEF='(def|class) '$FUNC

# Find all files that contain FUNCDEF
FILES=(`egrep "$FUNCDEF" $DIR/* -r -l --include=*.py`)

#
# Look for a function declaration within a files contents.
#
# <file>
#
function lookup_function {
    local line=`nl -b a "$1" | egrep "$FUNCDEF" | awk '{print $1}'`
    if [[ "$line" -gt 0 ]]; then
      # echo 'Jumping to --> '$1':'$line
      mate "$1" -l "$line"
      exit 0
    fi
}

# Iterate files
for file in ${FILES[@]}; do
    echo $file
    lookup_function "$file"
done

# Nothing found
echo 'Function '${FUNC}' was not found within the current project.'
```